# Iteration of JSON values only prints out one value to the DOM

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iteration

The `for (var of Object.values())` prints only one value and not all of them.

Don't understand why is this happening as it should iterate over each value and print out the all of the values.

Right now only the first block shows the values and the other one doesn't. I have put comments in `HTML` so that you can see where there results from `JSON` should be printed.

```js
const response = {
  "internal": {
    "services": {
      "core": "OK",
      "comments": "NOK",
      "id": "OK"
    },
    "db": {
      "pgsql": "OK",
      "redis": "OK"
    }
  },
  "external": {
    "gitlab": "OK",
    "trello": "OK",
    "geonames": "OK"
  }
}
const json = JSON.parse(response);

// Internal
for (let value of Object.values(json.internal.services)) {
  if (value === 'OK') {
    d3.select('#p-status').html('<p>No issues</p>');
    d3.select('.status-icon').html('<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>');
    d3.select('.status').classed('no-issues', true);
    loading.remove;
  } else {
    d3.select('#p-status').html('<p>Has issues</p>');
    d3.select('.status-icon').html('<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>');
  }
}

// External
for (let value of Object.values(json.external)) {
  if (value === 'OK') {
    d3.select('#p-status').html('<p>No issues</p>');
    d3.select('.status-icon').html('<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>');
    d3.select('.status').classed('no-issues', true);
    loading.remove;
  } else {
    d3.select('#p-status').html('<p>Has issues</p>');
    d3.select('.status-icon').html('<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>');
  }
}
```

```css
body>div>div>div>div {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #bfbfbf;
}

.fa-react {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: cyan;
}

.fa-comment {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.p-name {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#p-status {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

#p-status p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.group {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.status-icon {
  float: right;
}

.fa-check-circle {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: green;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.fa-exclamation-circle {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: red;
  padding-right: 5px;
  animation: pulseEff 1.5s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulseEff {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.has-issues {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.no-issues {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-11">
  <div class="status">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="row middle-xs">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2">
          <i class="fab fa-react"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">
          <p class="p-name">Core</p>
          <div id="p-status">
            <!-- this gets removed after the values are available, loading animation -->
            <img src="./src/img/Double Ring-3s-200px.gif" width="30" height="30" alt="loading-animation">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-6">
          <div class="status-icon">
            <!-- this gets removed after the values are available, loading animation -->
            <img src="./src/img/Double Ring-3s-200px.gif" width="30" height="30" alt="loading-animation">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-11">
  <div class="status">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="row middle-xs">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2">
          <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">
          <p class="p-name">Comments</p>
          <div id="p-status">
            <!-- this gets removed after the values are available, loading animation -->
            <img src="./src/img/Double Ring-3s-200px.gif" width="30" height="30" alt="loading-animation">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-6">
          <div class="status-icon">
            <!-- this gets removed after the values are available, loading animation -->
            <img src="./src/img/Double Ring-3s-200px.gif" width="30" height="30" alt="loading-animation">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated. I'll respond to every comment and answer.

Comment: A lot of useless code noise. You could localise it to few lines of code. Chances you would find your problem yourself when doing so.

Comment: At first I though of cutting of some code, but I thought that I should paste all the code that makes a component, and believe I even tried different methods, no results.

Comment: @JaredSmith tried, prints out `OK`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to think a little bit, to analyze my code deeply and after an hour or so I managed to fix my issue. The issue was not in `for ()` method, but I've mistakenly used the wrong function from `d3.js`.

So instead of using

```
d3.select('class').html();
```

I had to use

```
d3.selectAll('class').html();
```

I managed to fix this issue by using `Event Listener Breakpoints` in `Chrome Developer Tools`. I've noticed that `for ()` method works correctly but it only selects the first `class` nodes with same names in the DOM and not the rest. After rewriting the code from `d3.select()` to `d3.selectAll()` the issue was fixed.

I guess that "keep trying and don't quit" pays of in the end.

Answer (score 1):

No need to JSON.parse, it already is an object.

Comment: const json = JSON.parse(response);

Comment: Indeed. My bad, that will throw and is almost certainly (part) of the problem.

Comment: Yes I do need that, the console throws `Cannot read property of services of undefined`, but when I parse the object, then it prints out the value. I've put a static data, the data that I need is from a server.

Comment: Yes, that's right and I see your JS Bin is showing the results I need. If my code is ok, I'm wondering why does it print the result to only one node in DOM and not to all of them.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović, so I tried a couple of things. 

1. You mentioned Object.entries(obj) This behaves like so: 

`for(let val of Object.entries(json.internal.services)){ console.log(val) }` 
output: ["core", "OK"] ["comments", "NOK"] ["id", "OK"] 

2. You used `for (let val of Object.values(json.internal.services)) { console.log(val) }` 
output: "OK" "NOK" "OK" So your solution works as you wish. See here: link(https://jsbin.com/yukabibise/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that because you're not scoping your selection, you're getting the last value printed all the time. Take the `for` loop and cut down the noise a little..

```
var values=['a', 'b', 'c'];
for(var val of values) {
    d3.select('#someEl').html(val);
}
```

If I understand the d3.select correctly, it would select the same element every time, right? If so, you're *overwriting* the previous value on every iteration:

1. val=a, result is `<div id="someEl">a</a>`
2. val=b, result is `<div id="someEl">b</a>`
3. val=c, result is `<div id="someEl">c</a>`

You probably want to *append* your content..

```
var values=['a', 'b', 'c'];
for(var val of values) {
    d3.select('#someEl').append("<span>" + val + "</span>");
}
```

Comment: Tried, it doesn't work, but you are right about `you're getting the last value printed all the time` that's wha's happening. Nevermind, I'll figure something out.